# Como hacer para mostrar la imagen principal al compartir en Facebook con Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, facebook

Estoy intentando que mi sitio interactue con facebook. Me intereso mas que nada, el tema de compartir, pero este problema en si escapa al plugin que provee facebook me parece.

En si tanto con el boton compartir o de forma manual peganlo el link, facebook a veces no me muestra la imagen principal del articulo que quiero compartir. digo bien, a veces, porque para ciertos articulos lo hace correctamente, y en otras tantas me muestra otras imagenes de mi sitio que no tienen nada que ver con el articulo

Esto es azar? o hay alguna forma de que me detecte la imagen. He visto que en wordpress tienen algo llamado imagen destacada, y lo solucionan asi

```
<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8">

            <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrum">
                <li><a href="{{ route('front.index') }}">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('front.search.categoria',$articulo->categoria->nombre)}}">
                    {{$articulo->categoria->nombre}}
                </a></li>
            </ol>   

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">

                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                </span>
                {{$articulo->created_at->diffForHumans()}} |
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">
                </span>
                {{$articulo->autor->nombre}}
                <br><br>

                @include('front.template.partials.social.face-me-gusta')
                @include('front.template.partials.social.compartir-wapp')
                <br>
                <span class="titulo"><b>{{$articulo->titulo}}</b></span>
                <br>
                <h5>{{$articulo->copete}}</h5>
                <hr>
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$articulo->imagen->nombre) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <br>
                {!!$articulo->contenido!!}
                <hr>
                @include('front.template.partials.perfil-autor')
                <hr>
                <h4>
                    Si te gusto, Compartilo:
                    @include('front.template.partials.social.face-compartir')
                    @include('front.template.partials.social.compartir-wapp')
                </h4>       
                <hr>

                @include('front.template.partials.social.face-comments')    



            </div>             

            </div>      
        </article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como complemento a la respuesta de Muriano y poniéndolo en un contexto de vistas Laravel, puedes simplemente agregar el tag a tu layout principal con una imagen predeterminada y lo modificas en cada artículo o página, según lo que necesites:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="@yield('ogTitle', 'Título general de mi sitio.')"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Mi sitio web"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="@yield('ogUrl', 'https://misitioweb.com')"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="@yield('ogDesc', 'La descripción de mi sitio web.')"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="@yield('ogType', 'website')"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="es"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="@yield('ogImage', 'https://misitioweb.com/img/logo.png')"/>
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxx"/>
```

En tus vistas específicas lo modificas a tu gusto:

```
@section('ogImage')
    https://misitio.com/img/imagen-de-pagina.png
@stop
```

Debes tener en cuenta que la caché de Facebook es un poco "agresiva" y tan pronto hace el crawl de una página, generalmente debes indicarle que haga un flush de esta, de lo contrario te mostrará la misma información al momento de compartir por un buen rato.

Más información al respecto aquí: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: agregue el meta de imagen especificamente. Y si, me sigue tirando la misma imagen. pero no se bien que es hacer un flush. como seria eso?. insertando mi sitio en ese depurador de facebook me tira varios warning. no se como poder mostrarlo, dejo mi sitio: http://emap.com.ar/articulos/la-importancia-de-la-nutricion-en-el-deporte

Comment: Todo está en el enlace de facebook que está al final, ahí escribes la url de tu página específica, y luego te muestra que está bien o mal en términos de tags OG. Además hay un botón "Scrape again" (no sé como aparece en español) que hace el flush de la caché de Fb y lee la página de nuevo.

Comment: del tag q me interesa el warning me dice: URL no válida
Provided og:image URL, http://emap.com.ar/img/articulos/emap_1477106921.jpg was not a valid URL. // Pero es valida

Comment: Listo @Shaz era como dijiste. solo que mi chromium demoro en entender el cambio y esta en ingles ese boton.. por eso me gusta mas firefox (?). Gracias

Comment: Todo lo que indicás es correcto, pero algunos servidores la verdad que no permiten el uso de los OG tag, y eso lo complica mucho...

Comment: @AngelMariaGarciadelaMata no uses las respuestas para hacer comentarios (cuando tengas suficientes puntos podrás comentar en todas las publicaciones). Aparte, ¿podrías explicar eso de que algunos servidores no permiten el uso de OG tag? Los OG tags son parte del código generado en la página web, a los servidores no les importa. ¿Te refieres a algún framework en concreto?¿o alguna herramienta/plataforma?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a generar una serie de etiquetas "metatags" en tu sitio para indicar a facebook qué elementos quieres mostrar, en el caso de la imagen, puedes usar:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://davidwalsh.name/wp-content/themes/klass/img/facebooklogo.png"/>
```

Puedes ver algunas de las etiquetas "OpenGraph" diponibles aquí: https://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags

Y en esta otra, la documentación oficial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties